# Wire length between Raspberry and RC522

Tags: nfc

I want to know what is max length can be wired connection between Raspberry and RC522 module?

Comment: Ah, it depends on SPI speed, the lower the speed, the longer you can use the wires.I am playing with SPI 100kHz, 60cm, and found signals not distorted or noisy. If you convert 3V3 signal to 5V0, then it is OK to use longer wires.

Comment: This is my recent SPI 100kHz waveform, with 60cm wiring, in case you are interested: https://imgur.com/gallery/aFVfLg2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided that RC522 better connect to Arduino and when via USB to Raspberry Pi